# Any way to retrieve SQL Field Description property with a datarows query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-schema

I have a ProductInventory table with over 100 fields.  Many need to offer user guidance to understand.  I’m looking for a way to add tooltips to the form without hardcoding the text.

I want to use MS SQL table field property DESCRIPTION as the source for user tooltips during web forms data entry.

Generally, my descriptions are for other db admins, but I was wondering if with a little more thoughtful and friendly descriptions, I could make duel use of this extended SQL field property.

Is is possible to retrieve this field property WITH a datatable/dataset query?

Example:

FieldName: ProductID
Value: [string]
FieldDescription: “This is a description for the end user of what the ProductID  is field used for”

I know we can get the field schema for a specific field by…

```
SELECT @Result = count(1) 
FROM   ::fn_listextendedproperty (N'MS_Description',  N'Schema',  'dbo', 
N'Table',   '[Your Table Name]', 
N'Column',  '[You Field Name]')
```

Is this possible without a “per field” query on each field?

Perhaps run two queries. One to pull records and one to pull schema.
(i.e.  retrieve entire table schema and do a loop to find matching field name.)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those descriptions back via query for the whole table.

This is almost entirely lifted from [Phil Factor on SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic497713-8-1.aspx). My modifications are only the extra join condition p.name = 'MS_Description' and the where clause.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) AS [Table_Schema],
       tbl.name AS [Table_Name],
       clmns.name AS [Column_Name],
       p.name AS [Name],
       CAST(p.value AS SQL_VARIANT) AS [Value]
  FROM sys.tables AS tbl
       INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.OBJECT_ID=tbl.OBJECT_ID
       INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p ON p.major_id=clmns.OBJECT_ID
                                              AND p.minor_id=clmns.column_id
                                              AND p.class= 1
                                              AND p.name = 'MS_Description'
 WHERE tbl.name = 'Your Table Name'                                       
ORDER BY [Table_Schema] ASC,
         [Table_Name] ASC,
         [Column_ID] ASC,
         [Name] ASC
```

Comment: I think either of these ways may work. I will have to test to see which works best. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  select    
    s.name [Schema], 
    ao.[name] [Table],
    ac.[name] [Column],
    t.[name] [Type],
    p.[value] [Description]
    from sys.all_columns ac
    inner join sys.types t on ac.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    inner join sys.all_objects ao on  ao.object_id = ac.object_id
    inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = ao.schema_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sys.extended_properties p ON  p.major_id = ac.object_id  AND p.minor_id = ac.column_id
    where ao.type = 'u'
    order by s.name, ao.name, ac.name
```

with ao.type = 'u' (all user tables)

if you want only one table use ao.name = 'table_name'